# Rebuilding my SVN working copy from Scratch

Tags: .net, svn

my computer crashed this evening and now I have all kinds of issues with my working copy. I would like to reload the working copy from the server. How do I go about this? I am using Tortoise SVN

Answer (score 1):

First, try the "Cleanup" command in the menu.

If that doesn't work, rename the working copy directory, do a new checkout, copy in any modified files you might have in your old working copy, and then delete the old one.

Comment: It's in the default TortoiseSVN menu, and I don't think there is any situation where it is not shown. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html